# UNIX: why echo doesn't print in order?

Tags: unix, echo, ksh

I am writing a .ksh script in this HP-UX environment and below shows how it looks like:

```
IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator
for j in $(ps -ef | grep ora | grep ORCL | grep "LOCAL=NO" | grep Aug)
do
p=$(echo "$j" | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
echo "$p"
echo "$j"
done
```

I expected the code to print a process id, then a line, then a process id, then a line again .. and so on. However, in reality it echos all the process ids first and then all the lines. Why is it happening like this?

```
2490
2299
2573
2553
2455
2606
2469
2359
2627
4310
2327
2531
2562
2336
2446
3958
2517
2318
2499
2309
2426
2582
2508
2481
2596
2437
2544
2618
2369
2345
oracle 2490     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2299     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2573     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2553     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2455     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2606     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2469     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2359     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2627     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 4310     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2327     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2531     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2562     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2336     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2446     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 3958     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2517     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2318     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2499     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2309     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2426     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2582     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2508     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2481     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2596     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2437     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2544     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2618     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2369     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
oracle 2345     1  0  Aug  5  ?         0:00 oracleORCL (LOCAL=NO)
```

Comment: Maybe add debugging/trace info you your output, like `echo j=$j;echo p=$p` and you might see where it is breaking. Also, edit your Q to show what you get for `echo ${.sh.version}` ? Good luck.\

Comment: try to run the script with -X flag for live debug prints (e.g. bash -X ./myScript.ksh)

Comment: @nabeel: running a ksh script with bash is not a helpful debugging technique, even assuming that OP has bash installed on that system. (And I think you meant the `-x` option)

Comment: @shellter Thanks for your help. I used `echo j=$j;echo p=$p` and it shows me that loop actually iterates only once! it prints all the lines together as `j` and all the process ids together as `p`. Any idea why?

Comment: Your code seems ok. The only thing I can think is comment out the `IFS=` declaration OR if you are using inputs generated or transfered thru MS-Windows, then change `\r\n` line endings to `\n` with `dos2unix filename`. (You can check for `\r\n` with cat -vet filename | head -10` and if  you see ^M$` at end of lines, then that is your problem).  Finally, HP-UX is famously funky, it could be a bug (or feature). Going to bed. Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure your code is as shown? When I put the subcommand in double quotes I can reproduce your problem: `for j in "$(ps -ef | grep ora | grep ORCL | grep "LOCAL=NO" | grep Aug)" # Shows undesired behaviour`